# Telnet Minimalistic C# send prompt as two lines, not just as one

Tags: c#, command-prompt, telnet

I have a text in my textbox1 = `AlUsrx 287 tst001`

`AlUsrx` = is an script that I want to execute.

`287 tst001` = are two parameters that script needs to work.

I'm taking the `287` from `textbox2`
and taking `tst001` from `textbox3`

So I created my prompt string as follow:

```
("AlUsrx " + textbox2.Text + textbox3.Text);
```

and It doesn't work

when I send the string `AlUsrx 287 tst001` ...it sends as two lines
not as just one instruction line

this is what happens in my server:

```
:/>AlUsrx
```

(enter line, error saying: need the other two parameters"

```
:/>287 tst001
```

(enter line, error saying: obviusly, not ksh found"

but when I create the string with static value in textbox2 (287):

```
("AltaUsrx " + "287" + textbox3.Text);
```

this happened:

```
:/>AlUsrx 287 tst001
```

IT WORKS!

I guess the problem is that I'm taking the 287 as variable from textbox2 and it causes it to break my string in 2 lines.

Comment: A good programming book could be your best bet.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Comment: Answers belong in the answers section, not in the question. I have moved your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try string format.

```
var command = string.Format("AllUsrx {0} {1}", textbox2.Text, textbox3.Text)
```

Then pass the command in, you can then check the command in debug and make sure its formatting the way you are expecting.

Comment: Cool did it work for you? If so please mark this as the answer so others know. Thanks :)

Comment: What does the command show when you debug it, can you post it here? perhaps you are hitting enter or something and it is inserting a line break.

Comment: If I do that, I send 2 prompts orders:
:/> AllUsrx {0} {1}
...and then...
:/> 287 tst001

I tried sending the var command, and tried sending directly the order:
"AllUsrx {0} {1}", + textbox2.Text + textbox3.Text;
Any case, doesn't work!

Comment: No, I dont hit Enter key, I'm sending the order by a buttonclick_()

Comment: Can you show me the actual code. It sounds like you have something coded off.

Comment: I solved it :D
Thanks TONY anyway!!
stackoverflow dont let me put the answer, I should wait 8 hr to do that (cause I'm new user).
I'll put how I solve my problem when stackoverflow let me to do that!!

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Disclaimer. This was extracted from the question.</sub>

=====================UPDATE=======SOLVED PROBLEM===========================

I solve my own problem:

I was carrying 287 in textbox from a telnet connection, then the result in my richtextbox was:

`:/>tail -1 /etc/passwd|cut -d: -f3
287`

So I was cutting the characters from before and after 287 (to get only the 287):

```
string x = output.Substring(32, 4);
```

Then I was sending the x to my textbox

```
textBox2.Text = strID2;  //textBox2.Text = 287
```

AT THIS POINT THE TEXBOX WAS SHOWING THE 287 BUT....I was not seeing that there vas a "ENTER (SPACE)" character before the 2. I guess something like alt+0160

That character was making my code to separate my string as two!!

So, what I do to delete that character was delete it with substring...

```
string x = output.Substring(32, 4);

textBox2.Text = strID2;

textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text.Substring(1); //This is what I do at least to solve it.
```

That way, the hidden space or enter character was delete and now just keep the 287!! :)
Thanks "TONY" anyway for your help!
and "SoMoS" are you kidding me? .|.
get the ... out of here if you don't gonna say an intelligent comment.